# How to get access to the birthday of the logged-in person's friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-login

I am currently working on a web application project using the Graph API.

The goal of the project is to allow users to log in through Facebook, grant necessary permissions, and view their friends' birthdays. Additionally, users should be able to synchronize selected friends' birthdays with a virtual calendar, such as Google Calendar.

However, I found a lot of conflicting information on the internet. Is this application possible? When logging in, the user agreeing to allow access to friends and birthdays, is it possible to obtain a GET requisition in the Graph API and retrieve a json with the name and birthday of the logged in person's friends?

I tried using the Graph API Explorer, testing with different routes and I can't get the Json return.
I'm currently trying to do get on `me?fields=friends{birthday}friend-id?fields=birthday`

If anyone has experience or insights into this matter, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Additionally, I plan to open some issues related to this project that may need resolution, and I would welcome any advice or assistance in that regard.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: Your app will only be able to see friends of the user, who have also logged in to it and granted it permission to access their data. They would also need to grant it permission to access their birthday.